# Считать номер карты RFID со считывателя Z2 USB в C#

Tags: c#

Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста, какие библиотеки необходимо использовать для считывания номера карты RFID со считывателя, какие драйвера для считывателя наиболее актуальны и как это реализовать?

Comment: Немогу помочь - нужно закрыть???

Comment: Закрывайте тему

Answer (score 1):

В комплекте со считывателем идёт диск с драйверами https://ironlogic.ru/il.nsf/file/ru_443-S_Z-2_RD-ALL.pdf/$FILE/443-S_Z-2_RD-ALL.pdf

SDK от производителя https://ironlogic.me/en/software/developer-kits/sdk-readers

Там есть примеры "Examples of using libraries for several programming languages: ...; C# — "CSharp" folder; ...

Comment: Если ответ помог, то отметьте его как принятый.